# Can't Load asset files codeigniter

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've spent the last 7 hours trying to load my assets folder to my view file but for some reason it didn't work ! i read the docs , stackoverflow posts & tried everything but nothing seems to be working.

here's my folder structures:

```
htdocs
 CRM 
   app-assets
     css
        pages
          dashboard-ecommerce.css
        bootstrap.css
        bootstrap-extended.css
     vendors
        css
          vendors.min.css
          charts
            apexcharts.css
          extensions
            swiper.min.css  
  Applications
     controllers
       dashboard.php
     views
       dashboard.php
  assets
  (+ the rest of the files with .htaccess included)
```

Now here's the dashboard's header part:

```
    <!-- BEGIN: Vendor CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/charts/apexcharts.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/vendors/css/extensions/swiper.min.css">
    <!-- END: Vendor CSS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css">


    <!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app-assets/css/pages/dashboard-ecommerce.css">
    <!-- END: Page CSS-->
```

Note that  i did change the config file to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CRM'
```

but nothing worked.

Comment: Also i tried all the link combination possibe with
href="../app-assets/....Etc" or href="../../app-assets/....Etc" or href="../../../app-assets/....Etc"

Comment: have you tried   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=  base_url()  ?>/app-assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css">

Comment: need to set the base url link before trying it out right? let me check

Comment: its already set as per your query $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CRM'

Comment: just add <?= base_url() ?> in "href" or "src"  wherever userd as i showed in example.

Comment: @SandeepModak i did remove it when i've seen that nothing was working

Comment: when you see nothing working . did you check network tab ?

Comment: @SandeepModak the page load with plain HTML no style included. the problem is in locating the files !

Comment: @SandeepModak here's what i'm getting in the console

http://localhost/CRM/app-assets/vendors/css/charts/apexcharts.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210113/discussion-between-sandeep-modak-and-zakaria-sichaib).

Comment: The solution should be to begin each value of the `href` attribute with a slash (the "/" character), like, for example: `<link href="/app-assets/css/bootstrap.css" ...>`.

Comment: i fixed it ! the problem was in the .htaccess ! i had to add the |app-assets| next to assets in the : 

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|app-assets|solution|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)

 meaning that any file name i use should be added to the .htaccess ! DAMN IT thank god !

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution for this problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('app-assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('app-assets/vendors/css/charts/apexcharts.css')?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url('app-assets/vendors/css/extensions/swiper.min.css')?>">
```

base_url will proper base URL to the asset path.